# Remove Multiple Elements of same class in Angular but leave first one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to remove all elements of same class but leave the first one. How can I achieve this in angular?

```
var myElement = angular.element( document.querySelector( 'myclass') );
myElement.not(':first').remove()   //removes element
```

This is the error I am getting:
    ionic.bundle.js:21157 TypeError: myElement.not is not a function

Comment: `document.querySelector('.myclass')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.not()` function isn't defined in jqLite, `angular.element`, acording to this [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), doesn't implements all jQuery selectors and methods.

**UPDATE 1**

Here is an example.

```
var myElements = document.getElementsByClassName( 'myclass');

myElements = Array.prototype.slice.call( myElements ); // convert htmlcollection to array
myElements = myElements.splice(0, 1); //removes first from working list

angular.element(myElements).remove();   //removes remaining elements from the DOM
```

Comment: Yes agreed. Is there an alternative way of doing it? It works if I remove .not but obviously removes all elements.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example. I hope it helps. But, it's just one of many approaches.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the NodeList returned by `document.querySelector` to an array, you can shift out the first indexed value and then do a `.remove` on the rest.

```
var elements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".myclass"));
elements.shift(); // remove first item in the array
for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    angular.element(elements[i]).remove(); // remove each element from the DOM
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a clone of the first element.

```
first_element = myElement[0].clone
```

Remove the collection and use the first_element. If you are using underscore, you can do as below as well.

```
_.filter(myElement, function(element,index){ return index == 0; });
```